# How do I join two mysql statments and get the count for big data

Tags: php, mysql

Currently my code is like this:

```
<?php 
$qall = $db->query("SELECT * FROM location_code 
WHERE 
StateCode='".$secureStateCode."'");
while($fall = $db->fetch($qall)) {
?>
<tr>
  <th><?php echo $fall['StateCode']; ?></th>
  <td><?php echo $fall['StateName']; ?></td>
  <td>
  <?php
    $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `male_count` 
    FROM `all_users` 
    WHERE `Sex`='M' 
    AND 
    `StateCode`='{$fall['StateCode']}'");
    $data  = $db->fetch($query);
    echo $data['male_count']; 
    ?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?php
    $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `female_count` 
    FROM `all_users` 
    WHERE `Sex`='F' 
    AND 
    `StateCode`='{$fall['StateCode']}'");
    $data  = $db->fetch($query);
    echo $data['female_count']; 
    ?>
  </td>
  <td>Total male_count + female_count</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

How do I combine these queries and get them loading faster for the total of male & female. Currently I have about 500k users.

Comment: i think you want the later, but am not totally sure. you want the combined total, or a total for each male, and female?

Comment: @dqhendricks Absolutely yes..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$db->query("
    SELECT
        `Sex`,
        COUNT(*) AS count,
    FROM
        `all_users` 
    WHERE 
        `StateCode` = '{$fall['StateCode']}'
    GROUP BY 
        `Sex` WITH ROLLUP
");
```

Should return three rows, like so:

```
----------------
+ Sex  + count +
----------------
+  F   + 12345 +
+  M   + 54321 +
+ null + 66666 +
----------------
```

You should be able to get the rest from there =)

Comment: nirmala - you want to add another group on statecode too.  that way you will get two (or three if there are nulls in Sex) rows per state

Comment: That's the beauty of `WITH ROLLUP` -- add some more group-bys and you keep getting summaries =)

Answer (score 3):

You change this from you original query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `male_count` FROM `all_users` WHERE `Sex`='M'
```

To this

```
SELECT `Sex`, COUNT(*) AS `Amount` FROM `all_users` GROUP BY `Sex`
```

This is how I would do it in SQL, so I'm not sure if it works in MySQL. You would have to change the way your php handled the table as well assuming the results would be like:

```
Sex   |   Amount
-----------------
M     |    200000
F     |    300000
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the query do the work for you ... don't let a bunch of chatter requests do for you.

```
select
      PreQuery.StateCode,
      PreQuery.TotalRecords,
      PreQuery.Male_Count,
      PreQuery.Female_Count,
      LC.*
   from
      ( select
              au.stateCode,
              count(*) as TotalRecords,
              sum( if( su.Sex = 'M', 1, 0 )) as Male_Count,
              sum( if( su.Sex = 'F', 1, 0 )) as Female_Count
           from
              All_users au
           where 
              au.StateCode = $secureStateCode
           group by
              au.StateCode ) PreQuery
      join Location_Code LC
         on PreQuery.StateCode = LC.StateCode
```